# Quark confinement mechanism

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement

As far as I understood:

Quark confinement states that observing individual quarks is not possible, color charged quarks are confined into hadrons. As we try to pull them apart, force between them increases with the distance and thus more energy is added to the corresponding field. After a point, it is energetically more favorable to create quark antiquark pair instead of stretching the color flux tube more.

My question is that whether the quark confinement mechanism also applies to the quark antiquark pair or not. I would guess it does otherwise it means that we can observe them individually. But it's still better to get a confirmation if I am right or an explanation if I am wrong.

Comment: Confirmed. Keep reading. Why insist on not retracting the question?

Comment: @CosmasZachos How is the OP “insisting” on anything?

Comment: @G.Smith   Still there, isn't it? After reading on?

Comment: @CosmasZachos But when you wrote that the OP had not even read your comment! I do not understand why this question offends you so much. OK, it doesn’t show much prior research, but neither do tens of thousands of others that you don’t ask to be deleted. We are supposed to have a “Be nice” policy here. If you don't like the question I think you should just anonymously downvote it.

Comment: @G.Smith I am definitely not desisting from "being nice", admonitions to the contrary. Ultimately, it is handfuls of participants that have to laboriously  close these "just saying"s. Had the obvious confirmation and invitation to read on been heeded, the question would not be here any longer to provide a handle for this conversation.